# How to create CLR with return result

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, clr

I have CLR which references Web service, into CLR i have one method with calling one of Web services method. What i need is, to make this CLR method return me information and show it in Result tab (in SQL server) . 
I printed result in SQL tab Messages with `SqlContext.Pipe.Send`. How can I do the same in Result tab, like it's sample Selected table or Executed Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I already did it. So for them who had the same assue:
 If you have many rows and want to return all them then you have to do: For first row use `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(new SqlDataRecord(new(new SqlMetaData("name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500)));`
For second and more rows use `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(new SqlDataRecord(new(new SqlMetaData("name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500)))` 
and after `for` `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();`